# Dynamically changing markings in flot

Tags: javascript, flot

I can draw segments on a flot when I create is, by adding this to the options.

```
 markings: [
  { xaxis: { from: 150, to: 200 }, color: "#ff8888" },
  { xaxis: { from: 500, to: 750 }, color: "#ff8888" }
 ]
```

Now I want to delete these markings and add new ones by calling a function. I have tried the following, but it hasn't worked yet. I think I am not accessing grid in the right way. It is in the options, but not sure how to get to it. I also don't know how to remove the old markings.

```
   CustomPlot.prototype.setRibbons = function setRibbons(x1, x2) {
    alert("ok"); \\this works

    this.plot.getOptions().grid.markings.axis.from = x1;
    this.plot.getOptions().grid.markings.axis.to = x2;
    this.plot.getOptions().grid.markings.color = "#ff8888";
    this.plot.setupGrid();
    this.plot.draw();
```

Here is a [plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/NGdkDZshqScoo249YBxA?p=preview).

Comment: Have you [checked your console](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log) for errors? In your Plunker, you don't seem to have created the markings before so `grid.markings` is `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things to take care of to get the `setRibbons` function to work as expected in your plnkr.

First, you want to remove current markings by setting the option to an empty array:

```
this.plot.getOptions().grid.markings = [];
```

Then you'll want to re-add a marking for the options you passed before you redraw the plot:

```
this.plot.getOptions().grid.markings.push({ xaxis: { from: x1, to: x2 }, color: "#ff8888" });
```

Putting it all together, the `setRibbons` function looks like this:

```
CustomPlot.prototype.setRibbons = function setRibbons(x1, x2) {
    //remove old ribbons should there be any
    this.plot.getOptions().grid.markings = [];

    //draw new ones
    this.plot.getOptions().grid.markings.push({ xaxis: { from: x1, to: x2 }, color: "#ff8888" });

    this.plot.setupGrid();
    this.plot.draw();
}
```

I've updated your [plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fFntzHj3rok5qzXkFb2B?p=preview) as well.